# Understanding weak learner splitting criterion in gradient boosting decision tree (lightgbm) paper

Tags: machine-learning, cart, boosting, loss-functions, gradient

I'm trying to understand the description about gradient boosting in the light-gbm paper as in the picture below.

(Link to paper: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6907-lightgbm-a-highly-efficient-gradient-boosting-decision-tree.pdf).

In particular, my question refers to the formula in the definition. In gradient boosting trees, at one iteration we obtain the gradient values of our loss function and then fit a regression tree onto this gradient ('weak learner').

In the formula a specific splitting criterion used while building one of these intermediate trees is given. Additionally, in line 6 the authors mention that usually this splitting criterion is used in gradient boosting.

I wonder, where does the formula come from?

[image]

Comment: I haven't read the paper in detail, but usually for regression type decision trees, the splitting criteria is based on greedily minimizing the residual squared error.  This is a good read: https://www.benkuhn.net/tree-imp

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will read this in detail tonight. But isn't here the g_i our new label that we seek to predict? Because thats the gradient values and we fit a tree on the gradient. Also why the whole sum is in parentheses, which is then squared. Also they maximize this instead of 'minimizing the variance'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After I obtained some help from the authors, I can write down now how I understand it. Somebody jump in, if there is disagreement.

Say, we have some differentiable loss function $L(y,H(x))$ , where $H(x)$ is our tree ensemble at some iteration.
Let $g_i$ be the gradient of our loss function at some entry corresponding to observation i.

In each iteration, the gradient is our new label vector on which we fit a regression tree. Like, $\tilde{y_i} := g_i$

Let's only consider the gradient instances belonging to some parent node at some iteration. So, when I write $\forall g_i$ I mean all the instances in this parent node. Let $L = \left\{ g_j | x_{j,s} \leq d    \right\}$ and define R similar. Then we search the best variable s with splitting point d for the next split.

Therefore, we choose s and d according to

$ \min_{s,d} \sum_{g_i \in L}^{}(g_i - \bar{g}_L)^2 + \sum_{g_i \in R}^{}(g_i - \bar{g}_R)^2 - \sum_{\forall g_i }^{}(g_i - \bar{g})^2 \\
\quad =  \sum_{g_i \in L}^{}g_i^2 - n_L *\bar{g}_L^2 + \sum_{g_i \in R}^{}g_i^2 - n_R *\bar{g}_R^2 - (\sum_{\forall g_i}^{}g_i^2 - n *\bar{g}^2)  $

(as $\sum_{g_i \in L}^{}g_i^2 + \sum_{g_i \in R}^{}g_i^2 = \sum_{\forall g_i}^{}g_i^2 $, these terms cancel out)

$\quad =  - n_L *\bar{g}_L^2 -  n_R *\bar{g}_R^2 + n *\bar{g}^2  $

Now, $n *\bar{g}^2$ is always the same, independent of how we make the split. Hence, for the minimization we can ignore it. Therefore, the minimization from the first line is equivalent to:

$ \min_{s,d}\quad  - n_L *\bar{g}_L^2 -  n_R *\bar{g}_R^2  $,

which is equivalent to

$  \max_{s,d} \quad  n_L *\bar{g}_L^2 +  n_R *\bar{g}_R^2  \\
\quad \quad = n_L * (\frac{1}{n_L}\sum_{g_i \in L}g_i)^2 + n_R * (\frac{1}{n_R}\sum_{g_i \in R}g_i)^2 \\
\quad\quad =  n_L * \frac{1}{n_L^2} (\sum_{g_i \in L}g_i)^2 + n_R * \frac{1}{n_R^2}  (\sum_{g_i \in R}g_i)^2 \\
\quad\quad = \frac{(\sum_{g_i \in L}g_i)^2}{n_L}  + \frac{(\sum_{g_i \in R}g_i)^2}{n_R} $

This is almost exactly the formula from the picture but they weight this with the overall number of instances in the parent node. I assume, this is done to compare different splits between different nodes because they use best-first splitting.

Comment: This is very helpful. For me what ties it all together is that your starting point is interpreted as the reduction in variance from parent to the child nodes. Although for the variance we would need to divide by the number of data points in each node. I will try to work that out. Best.

Answer (score 0):

Section 3 in the LightGBM paper is valid for the MSE loss function for which hessians reduce to 1. In that case the formula from Definition 3.1. coincides with formulas (6) and (7) from the XGBoost paper (where they are derived in an understandable way).

Also, you can find in the LightGBM code (goss.php, line 110) that in GOSS data instances are actually sorted with respect to gradients multiplied by hessians, not gradients (as written in the paper), which are the same for MSE only.